# Excel Percentages for multiple numbers

Tags: excel

I know how to calculate percentage using a simple excel formula. I can't figure out how to do this with multiple numbers. For example: I have staff that are required to complete 100% of their work. Each staff member has accounts that need to be completed( i.e. 100 accounts) and  lets say 50 follow ups. The total accounts(100) will decrease as they complete and the follow ups(50) will decrease as they complete. The percentage complete for the total accounts and follow ups should = 100% of all work. I can't find an excel formula to calculate this.

Comment: Unless you want to give different weights to accounts and follow-ups: `(accounts completed + follow-ups completed) / (total accounts + total follow-ups) * 100 = percentage completed`

Comment: Never thought about weight but this might be helpful with follow ups since historically about 10% of the clients may not respond so the worker may need an 90% weight in this area. How can I assign a 100% and 80% weight to each task and still get to 100% of both task. Hope this makes sense. I really appreciate at you taking the time to comment. I'm pretty excel savvy but trying to strenghten my fourmula skills.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by the work is "completed". Simplistically, the percentage complete is just the sum of the work completed divided by the work targets.

```
=SUM(work_completed_range) / SUM(work_required_range)
```

This looks good on the surface, but assumes that the staff will stop work on one task when they hit the target in one area. Let's say the target for accounts is 100 and for follow-ups is 50 and a worker hates doing follow-ups. Using the formula above, they can do 150 accounts and no follow-ups and still hit 100% work completed. Is this okay or not?

When you say they are required to hit 100% of their work, I assume that means 100% in each area, so the worker above would be considered only 67% complete because out of the 150 tasks required, their 50 follow-ups were not done.

So we need to limit the credit they get in each area to the maximum of the work required (shown for the two tasks discussed):

```
=(IF(accounts_completed > account_required, accounts_required, accounts_completed) 
+ IF(follow-ups_completed > follow-ups_required, follow-ups_required, follow-ups_completed)) 
/ (accounts_required + follow-ups_required)
```

If you have a lot of these metrics, it would be easier to include a column for each task with a formula to calculate the task credit:

```
=IF(task_completed > task_required, task_required, task_completed)
```

Then we are back to a simple calculation of the percentage complete:

```
=SUM(work_credit_range) / SUM(work_required_range)
```

Of course, now we have another problem - your workers can toil ever so diligently and over-achieve, but they can only ever hit 100% productivity. This is a disincentive for your hard workers.

So what we want to do is give them their extra credit once they hit 100% in each individual task, which is when the sum of the task credit equals the sum of the tasks required.

```
=(IF(SUM(work_credit_range) < SUM(work_required_range),
 SUM(work_credit_range) / SUM(work_required_range),
 SUM(work_completed_range) / SUM(work_required_range))
```

[I assume you would have SUMs at the bottom of these columns, so this will just be the cells with the SUMs]

Now when a worker has 150 accounts done and 49 follow-ups done they will be at 99% but when they do one more follow-up and hit 50, they will get the extra credit for the additional accounts completed and be on 133%.

Comment: Chris- the max number of accounts an employee will ever be responsible for is fixed. However, i like the idea because when an employees work is 100% completed, they may help others and should get credit for this but the employee they helped should not be based on a 100% scale. For example if they started with 100 accounts and another employee assisted with 20; they should should be weighted some how by the 20 worked by someone else and the 80 they are working. Thanks for taking the time to respond.